# A word or idiom for something that is real but appears fake

Tags: nouns

A word or idiom for something that is real but appears to be fake.  For example "That photograph looks like a painting", or "the sunset looks fake".

Comment: You’ve actually almost given an answer in your own question: the phrase _so real it looks fake_ is not uncommon for exactly such a situation.

Comment: I guess pigs *do* fly...

Comment: Maybe *Pop Art*?

Answer (score 10):

Surreal, unreal.

- This painting is surreal.
- This is *unreal*, I am finally getting to meet Madonna.
- I am surrounded by a surreal atmosphere. I still can't believe that Rand Paul became the President.

> [un·re·al](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unreal)  (ŭn-rē′əl, -rēl′)
>   adj.
>
> 1. Not real or substantial; illusory.
> 2. **Slang So remarkable as to elicit disbelief; fantastic.**
> 3. Surreal.
>
> *The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.*
>
> [sur•re•al](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/surreal) (səˈri əl, -ˈril)
>   adj.
>   1. surrealistic.
>   2. having the disorienting, hallucinatory quality of a dream; unreal; fantastic.
>
> [1935–40]
>   sur•re′al•ly, adv.
>   sur•re•al′i•ty (-ˈæl ɪ ti) n.
>
> *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.*
>
> surreal - characterized by fantastic imagery and incongruous juxtapositions; "a great concourse of phantasmagoric shadows"--J.C.Powys; "the incongruous imagery in surreal art and literature"

Comment: +1 for *Surreal*. This is exactly the sense in which I use the word.

Comment: So do _surrealistic painting_ that appears _surreal_ by their very nature always appear to be fake? I don't think so. They may "elicit disbelief" but not in the sense of the OP's question.

Comment: Imagine you were Alice and walked into a painting, the huge pastel mushrooms. Imagine you walked into Roger Rabbit's world. If OP had a word other than "fake" then OP wouldn't need to ask this question.

Answer (score 3):

Consider *uncanny* and *uncannily*.

> [uncanny](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uncanny): beyond what is normal or expected

"That photograph looks *uncannily* like a painting."

"The sunset looks *uncannily* fake."

Answer (score 2):

"Too good to be true" Used when just as an example the sunset looks so glorious it looks fake.

An up to date and jokie one "She/That (must be)/looks photoshopped" looks so good it must be photoshopped.

Comment: "Too good to be true" is used almost entirely to describe situations that *are* too good to be true.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked! He asked about something that is real but appears to be false, not about something that appear to be real but is false.

Comment: ...or it is a perversion of "too good to be true" when "good" is associated to false.

Answer (score 1):

In France a while back, there was a scandal over some "*vrai faux*" passports, that is, official passports that were illegal.

In honor of that bizarre construction, I'd offer (in Engish): **faux faux** here, or if you prefer, **fake fake**. But yes, I realize that it's probably not what you want, since neither  occurrence of "*fake*" here indicates an intention to fool.

(FWIW, we used to occasionally see *Genuine Imitation Leather* stamped on some cheap articles.)

Answer (score 0):

All that is golden does not glitter. [Tolkien]

Answer (score 0):

I think surreal works if something really has that *dreamlike* or cartoonish qualities.  For something just vivid and painting-like then **picturesque** would be a good term.

> 1. like or suggesting a picture; specif.,
>
> a. having a wild or natural beauty, as mountain scenery
>
> b. pleasantly
>   unfamiliar or strange; quaint
>
> suggesting or calling up a mental picture; striking; vivid: a picturesque description

Answer (score 0):

*fantastic*. Am concerned by the apparent urge to reach so far for the exotic here. If nuance has been lost, restore it. Have the decency to beat us with a trudgeon and not a stick!

Answer (score -1):

[Apparent, apparently](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apparent) applied below with varying forms of increasing emphasis.

That photograph apparently looks like a painting.
The apparent painting was actually a photograph.
It is apparent.  That photograph looks like a painting.

That sunset apparently looks fake.
The apparent sunset was real.
It is apparent.  That sunset looks fake.

Comment: Why the down vote?